# How to convert sqlite3 to csv format using API for a chatbot?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, export-to-csv, chatbot

When I run my chatbot it creates a db.sqlite3 file in backend for storing all the conversation. I want to convert this db.sqlite3 file into a csv file using API. How should I implement it in python? The image contains the type of file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple tables in the db file associated with Chatterbot. They are conversation_association, conversation, response, statement, tag_association and tag. 
Out of all these tables only response and statement tables have proper data (at least in my case). However I tried to convert all tables into csv. So you may find some empty csv files too.

```
import sqlite3, csv
db = sqlite3.connect("chatterbot-database")  # enter your db name here
cursor = db.cursor()
tables = [table[0] for table in cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'")]  # fetch table names from db

for table in tables:
    with open('%s.csv'%table, 'w') as fd:   
        csvwriter = csv.writer(fd)
        for data in cursor.execute("select * from '%s'"%table):  # get data from each table
            csvwriter.writerow(data)
```

Comment: where to integrate it in my Chatterbot.py or do I need to make another file ? Please tell asap. Thanking you

Comment: ,Ok ,yes now its working. What is this StatementTable.csv and ResponseTable.csv indicating?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't know exactly. I just converted each tables into csv format.

Comment: BTW how you are getting the file names StatementTable.csv and  ResponseTable.csv? They should be Response.csv and Statement.csv according to my code right? did you modify the names?